# MFC: is it possible to to have view with multiple documents?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Is it possible to associate a view with different documents (**not** simultaneously of course)?
What I want to achieve: the application can have multiple documents of the same type, that can be added during runtime, and set of suitable views, the main of which is CFormview-based. The user can choose the number of the document to show per combobox in the toolbar. The views then associate themselves with this document and update with data from it.
Is it possible to achieve with CMultiDocTemplate?

If yes, how? especially is it possible to retrieve a document by it order number?

If not I'll probably have to abstain from using the templates altogether, which of course means more coding (and more questions to friendly community), but it will do what I want it to do and not Microsoft thought I should be doing

Comment: This sounds like arbitrary free association, sorry. But yes it's easy to retrieve a document by an associated id number, because it's easy to associate anything with an id number, and it it has nothing to do with MFC. But presenting the user with numbers is a huge leap back in history.

Comment: what do you mean by "arbitrary free association"? I basically want to reuse the same set of view for all documents

"But presenting the user with numbers is a huge leap back in history."
not neccesarily. you can't think of all situations;)

Comment: All of this is explained in [Programming Windows® with MFC, Second Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/mspress/books/1431.aspx). If you don't have a copy already, do get one. This is **mandatory** reading for any MFC developer.

Comment: Already recently read. That is probably a problem here. You read this book and now treat it like a holy scripture. Now if somebody comes and asks like me for something admittingly unconvential, you think he is ignorant of good wisdom. In opposite, it is exactly solving such questions is the best way to gain deep understanding, because it motivates deep dive research about something not described in a book.

And BTW this  is not a good book in terms explaining. "Ivor Horton's Beginning Visual C++" is way better on that point

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could but not out of the 'box'. Instead I'd recommend a different strategy. Rather than trying to attach a View to an existing CDocument derived class LOAD the Views CDocument with the information you want. That could done by adding a simple Copy method to the CDocument or you could move your actual data into a separate class then just point the CDocument to 'data' you want.

Trying to change the CDocument instance for a CView is going against the MFC grain which normally means lot of ASSERTS.

Comment: My current plan is like following: i'll write own DocTemplate, based on but not derived from CMultiDocTemplate.

Comment: I'll alter its behaviour in the following way: every Document gets the same set of pointers to the Views. After adding a new document or user choice, this Document updates CDocument pointers inside views to point to him, so the can show him and work with him.

Comment: You could simplify it by not having multiple CDocuments. Create your own 'document' class and have the single CView-CDocument point to the selected 'document'. Think of the CDocument as the switch between the available documents.

Comment: ah, I think there is a little misunderstanding.  you probably understood that that a single view represents a single document, so yu suggest kind of SDI approach.  Instead there will be a few _different_ views that  could represents a document. I want these views to be reused by multiple documents. I need multiple documents, but don't need them tobe shown or worked with at the same time. On the other hand the user should be able to switch beetween them seemlessly

Comment: No, I understood you ok. But I'm suggesting that you simply store a pointer to your 'data' in your CDocument rather than trying to re-attach the CView to a new CDocument. That way you keep the CDocument statically attached to the CView but you point the CDocument to the required data. It's just adding a layer of abstraction.

Comment: Or I could store an array of objects representing the data in a single document and use SingleDocTemplate. But then I'll need a few document methods just to forward the data from view to dataobjects. on the other hand it is less work than trying to invent own template. So I'll give a try to this approach and if will enable me to do exactly as I imagine it should be, I stick to rthis approach

Comment: Exactly. Build on top of MFC don't try and change it at the framework level.